# How to Add a reference between two BsonDocuments using MongoDbClient in C#

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to add a reference between two `BsonDocument` in C#, but unfortunately, I don't know and haven't found any documentation that explains how to do it.

Here is my code:

```
var parent = new BsonDocument( new BsonElement("name","parentTest"));
parent.Add("newField", "test");

var child1 = new BsonDocument( new BsonElement("name","childTest1"));
var child2 = new BsonDocument( new BsonElement("name","childTest2"));
```

I want to create a reference (one to many) between the parent `BsonDocument` and the two child documents (child1 and child2).

I have tried to use MongoDbRef, but without success.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After reading a lot of documents about the csharp provider without any lead, I have decided to read the php documentation and to follow the following steps:

1. To create the documents and the reference using the mongodb command 
   line client
2. Query the database using the csharp provider and see    what    kind
       of type the BsonDocument will return in the reference    values.
3. Recreate the same structure and see if the command line    client
       will    return the same json string.

I don't know is the official cshap provider have something that performs this for me, but I was unable to find any document explaining how to do it. So I have solved this question by myself. If someone knows an different or easier way to do it, please share your knowlegde here. Thank you all!

As result of my effort, I've created an extension method to make it easier. The code below is such class:

```
  public static class MyMongoDbExtension
  {
    public static BsonDocument GetDBRef(this BsonDocument document, string collectionName)
    {
      var id = document.GetValue("_id");
      var result =  new BsonDocument();
      result.Add(new BsonElement("$ref", collectionName));
      result.Add(new BsonElement("$id", id));
      return result;
    }
  }
```